# Problem with bsearch() implementation with array of strings

Tags: arrays, c, string, bsearch

As part of a coding task, I am trying to implement a version of `bsearch()` and I have experienced an issue with an array of strings.

this is the function I have created:

```
int binSearch(void *Arr, int Size, int ElemSize,
              void *Item, int (*compare)(void *, void *)) {
    BYTE *pArr = Arr;
    int found = NOT_FOUND;
    int left, right, mid, cmp;
    left = 0, right = (Size - 1);
    while (!found && left <= right) {
        mid = (left + right) / 2;
        cmp = compare(pArr + (mid * ElemSize), Item);
        if (cmp == 0)
            found = FOUND;
        else if (cmp < 0)
            left = mid + 1;
        else
            right = mid - 1;
    }
    return found;
}
```

this function seems to work fine with `int *Arr` but not with `char **Arr`. the function returns `NOT_FOUND` even thou the string is indeed in the array.

this is the calling function and comparison function I have created:

```
#define SIZE 100 // max Len for str is 99 chars

int stringBinSearch(char **strings, int size, char *str) {
    return binSearch(strings, size, SIZE, str, compereByAscii);
}

int compereByAscii(char *str1, char *str2) {
    return strcmp(str1, str2);
}
```

from what it seems, its a problem with `cmp = compare(pArr + (mid * ElemSize), Item);`, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Please post a [mre] with test data data that demonstrate the fault.  What is BYTE, FOUND, NOT_FOUND etc.

Comment: The search function calls your comparison function with a **pointer to an array element** and another similar pointer to the element to be found. Your array elements are **pointers to `char`**. Therefore your search function should interpret the pointers it is getting as **pointers to pointers to `char`**.

Comment: Errors include the calling code of `stringBinSearch()`.  Post a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comparison function gets a pointer to the array element, not the array element it self, so you must change the code to:

```
int compareByAscii(void *p1, void *p2) {
    char **strp1 = p1;
    char **strp2 = p2;
    return strcmp(*strp1, *strp2);
}

int stringBinSearch(char **strings, int size, char *str) {
    return binSearch(strings, size, sizeof(char *), &str, compareByAscii);
}
```

Comment: ohh you are right! I managed to make my code work without the pointer to the array element, but it's a bad habit to do it like that, I will change my function so that it will send a **pointer** to the ``char*`` element. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

ok, so like @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. mentioned in a comment here, The problem was with my comparison function, I called the function and gave it `char**`, however the function expected `char*`.

so I've changed the comparison function to this:

```c
int compereByAscii(char** str1, char** str2){
    char* s1 = (char*) *str1;
    char* s2 = (char*) str2;
    return strcmp(s1, s2);
}
```

And now the code seems to work as expected.

Comment: Why not simplify and 
` return strcmp(*str1, *str2);` ?